# Statement does not execute when using the database name in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This statement works:

```
INSERT INTO TestDB2.dbo.MyTableName SELECT * FROM TestDB1.dbo2.MyTableName
```

This statement works not:

```
DECLARE @SourceDatabase varchar(50)
DECLARE @TargetDatabase varchar(50)

SET @SourceDatabase = 'TestDB1'    
SET @TargetDatabase = 'TestDB2' 

INSERT INTO @TargetDatabase.dbo.PrcConfiguration SELECT * FROM @SourceDatabase.sppm.CONFIGURATION

OR without the '@'

INSERT INTO TargetDatabase.dbo.PrcConfiguration SELECT * FROM SourceDatabase.dbo1.CONFIGURATION
```

dbo and dbo1 are the schema.

I want to move later data from multiple tables from one database to another database using the same tables.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Please read the standard page for dynamic SQL in SQL Server: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass the DB name in such a query in variable, use dynamic querying instead:

```
DECLARE @SourceDatabase varchar(50)
DECLARE @TargetDatabase varchar(50)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SourceDatabase = 'TestDB1'    
SET @TargetDatabase = 'TestDB2' 

SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO ['+@TargetDatabase+N'].dbo.PrcConfiguration SELECT * FROM ['+@SourceDatabase+N'].sppm.CONFIGURATION'

exec(@sql)
```